# How can I pass an int to my onDraw(Canvas canvas) in Android?

Tags: android, parameters, ondraw

I use a surfaceview to draw a pie chart in Android. In order to know how big the pie slice should be I need to pass a parameter to the onDraw() method. How can I do this? Inside the onDraw() I make a query to a datahelper-class that fetches the right data.

I tried to call a static function in one Activity from the onDraw, and which function returned an integer. But I want something more dynamic, so I can send the integers I need to from the Activity to the onDraw and just get the result in form of a pie chart.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of solutions can be like this:

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView
{
    private MyParameter parameter;

    public void setParameter(MyParameter parameter)
    {
        this.parameter=parameter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if(this.parameter==null)
            return;  //nothing to draw...
        //draw here...
    }
}

//somewhere in code

MySurfaceView sView=(SurfaceView )findViewById(R.id.pie_chart);
//
sView.setParameter(new MyParameter(100,2000, false));

}
```

Comment: This worked. I didn't get it to work with an integer as parameter, so I used a string, is that how it is or should I be able to do a conversion?  Thanks anyway for a fast and useful answer!

Comment: Actually you can use as MyParameter Parcelable object and put there int, String and so on.

Comment: Hi! I was wondering if you might know how I could use this way to pass parameters to my SurfaceView during onTouchEvents? Is that even possible? If I want this parameter to be updated in the MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE.

Comment: @kakka47 - sure it's possible

Comment: I am trying this way, but it's not working:  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
 int xchanged = xdown- x; 
  xscroll = String.valueOf(xchanged);
    cv.setParameter(new String(xscroll));   
 cv.setParameter(new String(xscroll));  Is the "setParameter()" different when inside a touchEvent?